# Do python 'compilers' really compile the script or do they just run the script in an executable?

Tags: python-3.x, compilation, nuitka

For example `nuitka3` (you can get it via `pip3 install nuitka`)

Does it just take the source code of your script and put it like this in a C file?

```c
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    std::string src = "print(\"Hello world\")";

    system(("python3.10 -c " + src).c_str());
}
```

and compiles it afterwards or converts it the script to assembly like a real compiler?

Comment: Couldn't' you answer this yourself by creating such an executable and running it on a machine that does not have Python installed, which would remove the possibility of the `system` call being used?

Comment: @KenWhite Thats an interesting Idea but i don't have another machine that doesnt run python